# Find MIN, MAX, SORT and COMPARE in text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file `data.txt`:

> ```
> Jun/2015: 1028
> Oct/2017: 2048
> Jan/2010: 9654
> Aug/2006: 5702
> Feb/2018: 1984
> Oct/2012: 7749
> May/2008: 4722
> Jul/2016: 4722
> ```

I need a BATCH script to:

1. Find MIN, MAX value in file, the output is:

   - MAX of value is [max value after ":"], at [DATE of max value]
   - MIN of value is [min value after ":"], at [DATE of min value]
2. Sort the file data.txt by DATE of value (sort month and year of DATE together, not only month or year separate)
3. Compare DATE in file with current DATE, if DATE in file is greater than current DATE above 08 months, output those DATE with value after ":"
4. Find the DATE which had longest month (31 days in month) and output those DATE with value after ":"

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the value in text by for /f tokens=1,2 and sort the result by a-z, get the first line or last line in text such as the max or min line.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the minimum and maximum values you could use the following script (which also determines the rounded mean value); regard that this works for positive integers in a signed 32-bit room only; let us call it `stats.bat`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A "IDX=0, SUM=0"
set /A "MIN=(1<<31)-1, MAX=0"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%K in ("%~1") do (
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%L") do set "VAL=%%Z"
    set /A "VAL+=0, IDX+=1, SUM+=VAL"
    if !MIN! GTR !VAL! set /A "MIN=VAL" & set "MIN_DATE=%%K"
    if !MAX! LSS !VAL! set /A "MAX=VAL" & set "MAX_DATE=%%K"
)
set /A "AVG=(2*SUM+IDX)/(2*IDX)"
echo total amount:  %IDX%
echo overall sum:   %SUM%
echo minimum value: %MIN%   ^(%MIN_DATE%^)
echo maximum value: %MAX%   ^(%MAX_DATE%^)
echo average value: %AVG%   ^(rounded^)

endlocal
exit /B
```

To use it provide the text file as a command line argument:

```
stats.bat "\path\to\data.txt"
```

For the sample file `data.txt` included in your question the output would look like this:

> ```
> total amount:     8
> overall sum:      37609
> minimum value:    1028    (Jun/2015)
> maximum value:    9654    (Jan/2010)
> average value:    4701    (rounded)
> ```

---

For all the date-related computations you should use another language (like PowerShell), since `cmd`/[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) does not support date maths, neither does it support sorting by date.

Comment: Those who downvoted this answer, please tell me why!